# How to construct a graph of weights from an image

Tags: c#, image-processing

**Project: intelligence scissors.**
The first part of the project is to load an image (in the form of RGBPixel 2d array) then to construct a graph of weights to use it later to determine the shortest path between 2 points on the image (the 2 points will be determined by an anchor and a free point..In short i will have the source and the destination points).
I have a function that open the image and return a RGBPixel 2d array already made.Now image is loaded i want to construct the graph to do the i should use a function called **CalculatePixelEnergies** here is the code

```
public static Vector2D CalculatePixelEnergies(int x, int y, RGBPixel[,] ImageMatrix)
{
        if (ImageMatrix == null) throw new Exception("image is not set!");

        Vector2D gradient = CalculateGradientAtPixel(x, y, ImageMatrix);

        double gradientMagnitude = Math.Sqrt(gradient.X * gradient.X + gradient.Y * gradient.Y);
        double edgeAngle = Math.Atan2(gradient.Y, gradient.X);
        double rotatedEdgeAngle = edgeAngle + Math.PI / 2.0;

        Vector2D energy = new Vector2D();

        energy.X = Math.Abs(gradientMagnitude * Math.Cos(rotatedEdgeAngle));
        energy.Y = Math.Abs(gradientMagnitude * Math.Sin(rotatedEdgeAngle));

        return energy;
    }
```

This function use **CalculateGradientAtPixel**, Here is the code in case you want it.

```
private static Vector2D CalculateGradientAtPixel(int x, int y, RGBPixel[,] ImageMatrix)
    {
        Vector2D gradient = new Vector2D();

        RGBPixel mainPixel = ImageMatrix[y, x];
        double pixelGrayVal = 0.21 * mainPixel.red + 0.72 * mainPixel.green + 0.07 * mainPixel.blue;

        if (y == GetHeight(ImageMatrix) - 1)
        {
            //boundary pixel.
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                gradient.Y = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RGBPixel downPixel = ImageMatrix[y + 1, x];
            double downPixelGrayVal = 0.21 * downPixel.red + 0.72 * downPixel.green + 0.07 * downPixel.blue;

            gradient.Y = pixelGrayVal - downPixelGrayVal;
        }

        if (x == GetWidth(ImageMatrix) - 1)
        {
            //boundary pixel.
            gradient.X = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            RGBPixel rightPixel = ImageMatrix[y, x + 1];
            double rightPixelGrayVal = 0.21 * rightPixel.red + 0.72 * rightPixel.green + 0.07 * rightPixel.blue;

            gradient.X = pixelGrayVal - rightPixelGrayVal;
        }


        return gradient;
    }
```

In my code of graph construction i decided to make a 2d double array to hold the weights, here what i do but it seems to be a wrong construction

```
public static double [,] calculateWeights(RGBPixel[,]  ImageMatrix)
    {
        double[,] weights = new double[1000, 1000];
        int height = ImageOperations.GetHeight(ImageMatrix);
        int width = ImageOperations.GetWidth(ImageMatrix);

        for (int y = 0; y < height - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
            {

                Vector2D e;
                e = ImageOperations.CalculatePixelEnergies(x, y, ImageMatrix);
                weights[y + 1, x] = 1 / e.X;
                weights[y, x + 1] = 1 / e.Y;


            }
        }

        return weights;
    }
```

[an example for an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM4ay.png)

[an other example for an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exwdp.jpg)

Comment: Got an example image?

Comment: @J.vanLangen i added an image

Comment: 11x11 pixels..(I do not see much sense in the picture)

Comment: i put another example

Comment: I don't see whats wrong, but `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                gradient.Y = 0;
            }` setting the `gradient.Y` three times to zero?

Comment: @J.vanLangen ooh that doesn't make sense at all..sorry..
i have a question if i called CalculatePixelEnergies with parameters x = 1 and y = 1 isn't the returned value .x should be equal to the returned value .y with parameters x=0 and y = 2 ?